# Checksum error during installation of Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image from android sdk manager

Tags: android

I was trying to install Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1 from sdk manager but after complete installation it shows checksum error and nothing is installed.

It shows this message after complete(100%) installation.

Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 70273783312d4519f8b503cdd8be980180fb1197, got dd5b78240e3294ad26bff38bd8a32a0977a4b745.
done nothing

I already tried clearing up the cache and forced http method but it always shows that message at the end of the installation.